# BJT amplifier input out delay

Tags: power-electronics, bjt, digital-communications

I wanted to know, is there some kind of delay between the input and the output of the BJT amplifier leading to a phase shift?
I'd suppose there probably would be since there is propagation delay in the wires and between base and emitter.

So essentially how long does it take for the current to reach its maximum across Collector and emitter when the Vin sine signal reaches maximum

And if there is a delay, then it seems as current increases into RC, the voltage at the collector of Q1 would decreases since the voltage drop is now greater.

Then, is there a 180 phase difference between the Vin Sine and voltage across SPKR1?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Wouldnt let me add 'Hi guys' at the beginning so apologies if it sounds like 'Thor'

Comment: The speaker is inductive (meaning current lags voltage), which is probably a much greater effect than any normal transistor would case.

Comment: Okay but if we now replace the speaker with a resistor, im asking purely about the output of the circuit

Comment: You're talking about the properties of the speaker, i'm talking about the properties of the circuit itself

Comment: At audio frequencies, unless you have an authentic source of OC24 Germanium power transistors, the delay is practically 0. Then, you have chosen an inverting amplifier stage. Whether or not that results in an inversion at the speaker depends which way round you connect the speaker. (Note this circuit will give VERY disappointing results : driving 8 ohms from 100 ohms is very inefficient)

Comment: Yes, there will be delays, show me a circuit that doesn't delay a signal :-) Question is, **will you notice it?** This is a circuit for audio which means the signals are much slower than even simple electronics can handle. So no, you will not notice any delay. If you're building RF circuits using signals of hundreds of MHz, then yes, signal delay is an issue and needs attention. But for this circuit it is not so don't worry about it.

Comment: *Then, is there a 180 phase difference between the Vin Sine and voltage across SPKR1?* Oh, how terrible! No again, you will not notice this. Swap the speaker connections and you've counteracted that 180 degrees phase shift! Can you hear any difference? Only if you use **two** speakers and phase-change one of them, you will be able to hear that. With one speaker that's impossible. Human ears cannot detect the absolute phase.

Comment: Oh and don't leave this circuit on too long as it is really ineffcient and will drain the battery quickly. If you need a proper audio amplifier, buy an LM386 based amplifier module.

Comment: You'll run into delay problems if the transistor saturates, because recovery from saturation takes a long time. Other than that, you won't have enough of a delay to be remotely noticeable from the transistor itself--the speaker will give far more of a delay.

Comment: You cannot drive an AC load smaller than the DC source since the resistor cannot pull up the load.  Most of the delays are all between the cone and your ears except for phase inversion

Answer (score 0):

Phase shift and time delay are two different things.

At audio frequency, that is in the kHz range, the output voltage to input voltage propagation delay of this circuit is zero.

You might have propagation delay effects if the wires were 1 mile long.

The BJT does not introduce propagation delay unless the input signal is in the GHz range.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very poor class-A inverting amplifier that produced a very low max output power but wasted a lot of power making heat even when it was not playing any sounds.
I increased its output power 58 times but it is still very low.
[image]